# Битрикс добавить свойство элемента инфоблока в список свойств, выводимых на странице детального просмотра (DISPLAY_PROPERTIES), через api

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть инфоблок с id `$iblockCatalogId` и свойство элемента инфоблока с id `$propId`.

В шаблоне детальной страницы элемента в массиве `$arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']` выводятся свойства, отмеченные для вывода в паблике.

Задание `DISPLAY_PROPERTIES` для детальной страницы через настройки комплексного компонента на скриншоте:

[image: Задание DISPLAY_PROPERTIES для детальной страницы]

Как **через api** Битрикс добавить свойство в список выводимых свойств?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. Выводить свойство этого же инфоблока? API не нужно. Просто добавьте код свойства в поле. Если свойство другого инфоблока или какая-то нештатная привязка, то надо редактировать код компонента. Уточните свой вопрос. Передать свойство через API просто откройте страницу на которой подключается компонент. Если это свойство того инфоблока с которым работатает компонент, то в массив выводимых свойств добавьте код нужного свойства, по аналогии как это сделано для существующих.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Открыл страницу подключения компонента и обнаружил, что свойства для вывода на странице детального просмотра задаются в виде массива символьных кодов `"DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(<символьные коды свойств через запятую>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ожидал что свойства элемента инфоблока для вывода на детальной странице элемента задаются где-нибудь в БД и для этого есть метод апи.

На самом деле эти свойства задаются в параметрах комплексного компонента `bitrix:catalog` (например, на странице `/catalog/index.php`) в php-массиве:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog",
    "catalog",
    array(
        // тут куча других параметров

        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            // массив символьных кодов выводимых на стр. детального просмотра свойств
            'ATT_PROP_1',
            'ATT_PROP_2',
        )
    )
);
```